# Export to csv with respond_to returns errors on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, export-to-csv

With Rails version 5.2.rc1

if I use

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render(csv: "test") }
end
```

results

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

What is the best way to export to csv in rails 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into the [Railscast's](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) screencast. If you followed everything properly and still you're getting the error, then try something like this in your routes:

```
match '/yourPathTo.csv' => 'controller#action', via: :get, defaults: { format: :csv }
```

Answer (score 1):

Guess u missed default format part in route of this action.

```
, defaults: { format: :csv }
```

Appending above code to your route may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add format.html before format.csv

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { render(csv: "test") }
end
```